# error: TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

I'm using Angular 8, if I use the command "ng serve" I get this error in the angular-error.log:

```
[error] TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__extends (C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\07-bonus-LoginApp\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:67:9)
    at C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\07-bonus-LoginApp\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\template.js:115:17
    at C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\07-bonus-LoginApp\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\template.js:314:6
    at C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\07-bonus-LoginApp\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\template.js:3:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\07-bonus-LoginApp\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\template.js:9:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\07-bonus-LoginApp\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\transform.js:20:22
    at C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\07-bonus-LoginApp\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\transform.js:10:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\07-bonus-LoginApp\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\transform.js:16:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
```

I already tried deleting the node_modules and running **npm install** command and **npm clean-install**, but it won't work, could someone help me out?

Comment: did you also try deleting the package-lock?

Comment: wecome to Stack Overflow ! Please review the guidelines on how to ask questions. You will greatly improve your chances of getting good answers if your question has context and shows some efforts  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask